# Need an example

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number. I need an example of finite group $G$ generated by the elements of order $p^n$ ($n\in \mathbb N$) , which contains a normal subgroup $H$ that is not generated by the elements of order $p^n$.

Despite the question is probably very simple, this is not a homework problem. I'm an isolated mathematician and group theory is definitely not my strong side (I could probably solve this problem by myself, but I would spend 2 hours to do that).

Comment: Hint: $G=S_3$  works. Also, 2 hours is not a long time for a mathematician  to work on a problem .

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. Thanks again. You're probably right in general, but when the problem is elementary and only secondary relative to your main research + you need to go work 10h/day + 3 children, this may appear to be very long. In fact, this depends on what you call a "mathematician" (in my opinion, this does not mean necessarily "professional mathematician").